# JSON stringify manipulation

Tags: json, stringify

Take the code:

```
JSON.stringify({ "x": 1.0 });
```

the output will be

```
{"x":1}
```

I have tried everything using toFixed(), parseFloat(), +() and many others but cannot for the life of me get it to return:

```
{"x":1.0}
```

I can get it to return:

```
{"x":"1.0"}
```

but I just can't get

```
{"x":1.0}
```

Is this possible? I am leaning towards no.

Comment: If you can't figure out a way, I would suggest adding post processing to the string if your object is predictable enough. Check for a decimal place after your var name and value and if it lacks one add ".0".

Answer (score 0):

If you need the float to be displayed in a particular way, you need to leave it as a string.

However a better solution would be to just leave it as a Number and let the client/view format it.

Comment: I'm submitting the JSON data against a java servlet that requires the number to be a double. It fails otherwise.